# What does this nginx C code do?

Tags: c, nginx

This is from nginx.c. I am curious about its nature since it seems to look very strange but I don't know enough C to make a judgement about it.

```
 608 #if (NGX_SETPROCTITLE_USES_ENV)
 609 
 610     /* allocate the spare 300 bytes for the new binary process title */
 611 
 612     env[n++] = "SPARE=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 613                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 614                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 615                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
 616                "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
 617 
 618 #endif
```

Comment: It says it right there in the comments `/* allocate the spare 300 bytes for the new binary process title */`

Comment: yes but why this ugly and long way? is this a normal technique?

Comment: Without seeing the whole file it's hard to say, but it looks like that long bit of text is just a human readable placeholder in some text file. It's not allocating any memory or anything, as that must have been done before this line is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It is simply reserving some memory (300bytes) at a specific location in memory (pointed by `env`)

Indeed it is crude and dirty and NOT a good way to do so.

#### Why use it then?

The problem being solved is peculiar and this is a simple way to solve it,
which is [**well explained in the nginx code itself**](http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c#0012).

The gist is that there is no way to specify the size of `argv[]` to our liking. Hence we reserve some space at the start of the object that immediately follows it in memory i.e. `env`.

---

The clue to understanding this was to note that this code is invoked ONLY if [**`NGX_SETPROCTITLE_USES_ENV`**](http://lxr.nginx.org/ident?_i=NGX_SETPROCTITLE_USES_ENV) is defined and then following the trail.

Comment: Interesting. Nice research! :)